# Extract or reconstruct HTML from an AXWebArea

Tags: webkit, accessibility-api

I have an AXWebArea that I can access via the Accessibility API.  Is there a way to extract or reconstruct the HTML used to create the AXWebArea?  The app I am debugging is modifying HTML prior to loading it into an AXWebArea and I'd like to understand what modifications it is making.